# How to have coinslider.js images resize with backstretch.js

Tags: jquery, image, resize, slider, jquery-backstretch

I'm trying to have coinslider resize the images to 960 by 360. When I try it makes the slider itself 960x360 and not the image. So if I use an image that's 1920x1080, it'll only show the top-left portion of the picture rather than resizing it. I inpsected the element and found that coinslider was taking the images in the  tags and adding it to the div style of background-image. I tried css and no luck, and I tried using backstretch on the div.

These aren't working :(

```
$('#coin-slider').coinslider({width: 960, height: 360});
$('#coin-slider').backstretch;
```

maybe I need a jquery  .change event to detect when #coin-slider style tag changes and then to add

```
background-size: 960px 360px;
```

Not really sure how to do that and lost.

Comment: have you tried to add a width and height to an images in css ?? eg. `#coin-slider li img {width: 960px; height: 360px;}`

Comment: i was wanting it to be responsive but I long gave up with coinslider. I can just make sliders now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just closing this post as I just make a new slider and had it compatible with backstretch.js. Coinslider was doing a bit too much on the page for backstretch to function and resize properly.